# session_start(); doesn't work?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I've solved my last problem, but I have another now.
I have searched on google and stackoverflow for hours now, I think. But i can't get it to work.

When I login, using this:

```
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));

                $checkUser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
                $checkUserResult = $mysqli->query($checkUser);

                if($checkUserResult->num_rows > 0) {
                    $userRow = $checkUserResult->fetch_assoc($checkUserResult);

                    $dbid = $userRow['id'];
                    $dbuser = $userRow['username'];

                    $_SESSION['id'] = $dbid;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                    header("location: me.php");
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='errorField'>Anv&auml;ndarnamnet och/eller l&ouml;senordet &auml;r fel!</div>";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

It's redirects me to the me.php, wich is this codes:

```
<?php
include "core/global.php";
echo (headers_sent())?'sent':'not sent';
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { header("location: index.php"); } ?>
```

But then it redirects me back to the Index.php (cause of the session) and if i try to use

```
echo (headers_sent())?'sent':'not sent';
```

It says 'not sent'

The session doesn't work... for some reason I dont know.
My friend, who Is a OOP "pro" can't even solve this... so please, help me!

Thanks.

PS. The session_start() on the login page, is on THE TOP OF THE PAGE:
**http://prntscr.com/1g7ohh**

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be at the **top** of every page used.

Comment: What's in `core/global.php`?

Comment: Wat exactly does not work can you clarify?

Comment: @Pekka웃, It won't start the session... I think.

Comment: @Blender Database connection.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: You need to turn error_repoting on ... I'm sure your server is trying to tell you what is wrong.... `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: @JonasTornerai In regards to `headers_sent()`, that is a `function`. What is inside that function?

Answer (score 2):

This line in me.php...

```
echo (headers_sent())?'sent':'not sent';
```

is breaking your session_start call.

By outputing text you are forcing headers to be sent.

replace with

```
if (headers_sent()) die ("Headers have already been sent");
```

That way you are not sending the headers while testing to see if the headers are sent :)

Comment: You wrote `if (headers_send())` isn't that supposed to be `if (headers_sent())`?

Comment: @JonasTornerai Fred caught this one... should be headers_sent... updated code

Comment: @JonasTornerai If you tried his answer with `if (headers_send())`, try it now and see if that works. It was edited to `if (headers_sent())`.

Comment: It stills redirects me to index.php.

Comment: @JonasTornerai Then try a `var_dump` and post your results.

Comment: @JonasTornerai then if($checkUserResult->num_rows > 0)  must be false and you are getting output or you are in a redirect loop... which one is occuring?

Comment: var_dump(session_start)) is bool(true)

Comment: array(2) { ["id"]=> NULL ["username"]=> NULL }

Comment: @JonasTornerai This may or may not be relevant, however I have seen a similar case where the fault was a syntax error in the **form** used. Just saying.

Comment: @JonasTornerai Try using `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` instead, see if that makes a difference. Maybe by you leaving out the `echo`, is making it do some strange things.

Comment: @JonasTornerai oh crap, I was so hoping it would've been that.

Comment: Could someone try to help me through TeamViewer or something..?

Comment: @JonasTornerai This is all that's left that I can think of. I'm "picking at straws here, of course" but try this: `$dbid = $_SESSION['id'];` instead of `$id = $_SESSION['id'];`.

Comment: @JonasTornerai Only thing now that I can think of is, that the trouble may lie in your database connection. Other than that Jonas, I don't know what else to tell you, except go for a total re-write.

Comment: Problem solved! I changed $userRow = $checkUserResult->fetch_assoc($checkUserResult); to $userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($checkUserResult);

Answer (score 0):

In your login example you don't seem to be starting the session.

Add `session_start();` to the top of the file, unless you're not showing us the rest of the code. Remember, you always need to start the session if you want to use it.

Comment: @JonasTornerai From what I gather by your screenshot, you have `include "core/global.php";` above `session_start();`, or does that not make a difference? And above `echo (headers_sent())?'sent':'not sent';` also.

Comment: Yes, but I've changed the code now. session_start() is at the top of the file - but it doesn't work.

Comment: @JonasTornerai You also have `echo (headers_sent())?'sent':'not sent';` above `session_start();`, have you changed that also? Try to put it above all `include "core/global.php";` inclusions.